# Can aldol reaction occur during α-halogenation of ketone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aldol-reaction

I know both aldol and $\alpha$-halogenation reaction well.

I know that in and aldol reaction, the carbonyl containing molecules like ketones and aldehydes attacks themselves when base like $\ce{OH-}$ attacks $\alpha$-proton.

The same thing also happens in $\alpha$-halogenation of these carbonyl containing molecules.

So my question is that in presence of halogen, before the double bond of the enol can attack halogen atom of $\ce{Br2}$, $\ce{Cl2}$, $\ce{I2}$ in $\alpha$-halogenation, can aldol reaction reaction occur by double bond of the enol attacking another carbonyl containing molecules?

Comment: Hello, I have edited your question using MathJax. Learn more on how to use it here: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here

Comment: @PrittBalagopal You can (and should) also edit out [unnecessary "statements of weakness"](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/593/4945), like *thanks* and similar salutations.

Comment: Carbonyl compounds, in general are quite bulky and poorly electrophilic They only react when no other better electrophile is around. The major products would definitely be the $\alpha$-halogenated ketone, while some minor amounts of aldol may form.